# How can one demonstrate that sponsor's fund will be available to the applicant?

Tags: visas, uk

I am applying for PLAB visa for UK to sit in PLAB 2 and I am being sponsored by my uncle entirely for the trip.

I was wondering how can I demonstrate that the funds will be available to me during the trip? I mean, shall I make a transfer of the sponsored amount from his bank account to my account  and show the bank document related to transfer  or I don't need to make any transfer but rather simply an affidavit stating that he will bear all costs of my trip will suffice?

Of course, I am going to provide the other documents like his bank statement of 6-7 months, income tax returns of 3 years, relationship proof etc etc.

Comment: Especially the section "Can I use a co-sponsor?".  Based upon the info you provided your application will be incredibly weak. Please read the linked article above.  See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=plab